# pyqt5で描いた3次元グラフの視点をマウスで動かしたい

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

pyqt5で描いた3次元グラフを、マウスでドラッグしたときに動くようにしたいです。下は試しに書いたグラフです。

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication, QVBoxLayout


from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image, ImageOps
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5 import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

class Main(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)

        x = np.arange(-3, 3, 0.25)
        y = np.arange(-3, 3, 0.25)
        X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
        Z = np.sin(X)+ np.cos(Y)

        self.figure1 = plt.figure()
        #self.axes1 = self.figure1.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
        self.axes1 = self.figure1.gca(projection="3d")
        self.canvas1 = FigureCanvas(self.figure1)
        self.canvas1.setFixedSize(600,450)
        self.toolbar1 = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas1, self)

        self.axes1.plot_surface(X,Y,Z,cmap='jet')

        layout1=QVBoxLayout()
        layout1.addWidget(self.toolbar1)
        layout1.addWidget(self.canvas1)
        self.setLayout(layout1)

        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Main()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

これを実行すると次のようなGUIが出来ます。
[image: 画像]

しかし、これではグラフをドラッグしてもグラフの視点は変わりませんでした。ここでグラフの視点が変化するように表示することは出来るのでしょうか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[QTimer](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/api/qtimer.html) で定期的に関数を呼び出し、[QCursor](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/api/qcursor.html) から得た位置情報を元にグラフを回転させ、再描画すれば出来ました。グラフの回転には [`view_init(elevation, azimuth)`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.html?highlight=view_init#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.view_init) が使えます。マウスがクリックされたかどうかは、FigureCanvas を [`mpl_connect()`](https://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html) しておけば `mousePressEvent` や `mouseReleaseEvent` で検知できます。

具体的には以下のようにします。まずいくつか追加で `import` します。

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QTimer, QPoint
from PyQt5.QtGui import QCursor
```

質問文のソースコードの `__init__()` にタイマーを起動するコードを加えます。

```
self.timer = QTimer(self)
self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update)
self.timer.start(100)  # ここが更新速度 (ミリ秒) になります
```

更に `__init__()` で `mpl_connect()` すると共にドラッグ用の変数を初期化しておきます。

```
self.canvas1.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.mousePressEvent)
self.canvas1.mpl_connect('button_release_event', self.mouseReleaseEvent)

self.startCursorPos = QPoint(0, 0)
self.isDragging = False
self.elev = 0
self.azim = 0
```

マウスが左クリックされているか検知するためのメソッドを用意し、

```
def mousePressEvent(self, event):
    if event.button == Qt.LeftButton:
        self.startCursorPos = QCursor.pos()
        self.isDragging = True

def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
    if event.button == Qt.LeftButton:
        diff = QCursor.pos() - self.startCursorPos
        self.elev += diff.y()
        self.azim -= diff.x()
        self.update()
        self.isDragging = False
```

最後に、再描画するメソッドを定義しておきます。

```
def paintEvent(self, event):
    if self.isDragging:
        diff = QCursor.pos() - self.startCursorPos
        self.axes1.view_init(self.elev + diff.y(), self.azim - diff.x())
        self.canvas1.draw()
```

とりあえずこれでグラフが回るようになります。

### 参考

- [how to set “camera position” for 3d plots using python/matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12904912/5989200) -- Stack Overflow
- [mplot3d example code: rotate_axes3d_demo.py](https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/examples/mplot3d/rotate_axes3d_demo.html) -- matplotlib
- [Qt 5, get the mouse position in a screen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32040202/5989200) -- Stack Overflow

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！確かにマウスの位置に対応してグラフの視点も動きました！ただ個人的にはグラフをドラッグしたときだけに動いてほしいので、もう少し改良します。分からなくなったらまた聞くかもしれません。何はともあれ、回答ありがとうございます。

Comment: @toma さん、すいません、ドラッグしたときだけ反応するようにするのを忘れていました。回答を更新しましたのでご覧ください。

Comment: 凄すぎです。思いのままに動きました。